A public IP associated with private AKS cluster. IP tag is aks-slb-managed-outbound-ip
I am using Private AKS cluster and I don't want to connect it to any Public IP address. AKS load balancer mode is Standard and we are using internal load balancers in AKS and it is not creating any public IP address, it using the IP addresses from the node pool subnet for load balancer IP.
When when search "Public IP addresses", In Azure, we can see a public IP address which is attached to Kubernetes and the tag is aks-slb-managed-outbound-ip.
Some documentations are saying, Azure need this IP address for connecting AKS to other Azure resources and egress traffic and they will take care of its security as it is made with zero trust security mode. Yes, I can block IP address access in NSG.
But my question is, is there any method to create Private AKS cluster without a single public IP address?
